# RemoveChild and appendChild element not being removed or appended

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I have this script that is working when I look in the console but does not affect the page. The `accountLink` is not removed and `userIcon` is not replacing it.

I expected accountLink to be removed and userIcon to appear.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const userIcon = document.createElement('i');
  const accountLink = document.getElementById('account-link');
  const accountWrap = document.getElementById('account-link-wrap');
  userIcon.className = "fa-light fa-user";
  accountWrap.removeChild(accountLink);
  accountWrap.appendChild(userIcon);
  console.log(userIcon);
}
```

```html
<ul class="et-social-icons">


<li class="et-social-icon subscribe-side">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/subscribe'); ?>">
        <span style="color:#D20018">Subscribe</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="et-social-icon account-side">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/my-account'); ?>">
        <span id="account-link-wrap"><p id="account-link">Sign In</p></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="et-social-icon basket-side">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/basket'); ?>" class="icon">
        <i class="fa-light fa-cart-shopping"></i>
</li>



<li class="search">
    <a class="search_icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span>Search</span></a>
    <div style="display:none;" class="visform"> <?php get_search_form(); ?></div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML as well?

Comment: And the CSS for `.fa-light` and `.fa-user` besides the HTML?

Comment: Thanks, ive added HTML. The css for fa-light is font-awesome pseudo-class .fa-cart-user:before, .fa-user-cart:before {
    content: "\f07a";
}

Answer (score -2):

I tested exactly your code with some example HTML and it works, see the example. Maybe your HTML part is wrong.

It's also being replaced in the HTML. Here is an [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pcu1ho64/1/).

```js
    window.onload = function() {
        const userIcon = document.createElement('i');
        const accountLink = document.getElementById('account-link');
        const accountWrap = document.getElementById('account-link-wrap');
        userIcon.className = "fa-light fa-user";
        accountWrap.removeChild(accountLink);
        accountWrap.appendChild(userIcon);
        console.log(userIcon);
    }
```

```html
<div id="account-link-wrap">
  <div id="account-link">
    Account Link
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem does this solve? Please see [answer] (and [ask], so you know what's expected in a question).

Comment: Thanks Asobitu. Can you see any problem in html above? I just added it. Thanks!

Comment: @Visible The only thing i see is that you forget to close one a-tag around the cart icon. I tested it also with your new posted HTML and it seems to work in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yrnb09po/ (EDIT: i added the class "fa" to make it work in fiddle but this can be something version related. I never used Font Awesome before :) but maybe it helps also)

Comment: Thanks asobitu. Very. starnge just doesnt seem to be affecting the elements by id even though they are there. Thanks for your help.